# Cant implement CI/CD with gitlab

Tags: gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, cicd

i'm new with CI/CD. i have created a simple .gitlab-ci.yml, I can go into the server but at the end it shows me

```
bash: keys/relation-fe: Permission denied
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

on my gitlab pipeline. My gitlab-ci.yml file configuration is given below.

```
deploy-prod:
  tags:
    - ci
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  script:
    - bash .gitlab-deploy-prod.sh
```

And the deploy-prod.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get server list 
set -f
string=$DEPLOY_SERVER_IP
array=(${string//,/ })

# Iterate servers for deploy and pull last commit 
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
  echo "Deploy project on server ${array[i]}"
  ssh bitnami@${array[i]} " "$("ssh-add")" keys/relation-fe && cd htdocs/relation-fe/ && git pull "
done
```

My target is to whenever I commit changes and push my code to GitLab the code should be automatically deployed on the server. Can anyone fix the issue for me? I'm really frustrated and can't fix it for a long time.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Looking like a quoting error in the script. Look at your opening and closing quotes carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, 
is this line correct?  "$(ssh-add)"  or should I use  $(ssh-add)  this?

Comment: @sytech could you please tell me how I could add the command ssh-add inside the quotation marks? i think the problem is there.

Comment: `ssh bitnami@${array[i]} " "` looks like you're passing the string `" "` here and I'm guessing you didn't actually want to do that.